# editing table fields in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am having an issue when adding a user to my User class in the parse database.The only results after I restart my parse.com webpage in my User's table is

**Users**

android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{258e641a VFED..CL ........ 20,68-684,159 #7f0c0051 app:id/userloginname}
Bankgo
Maniw

---

I want the next User field to be what the user enters oppose to some generated ID. I am a bit confused. Can someone assist me?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(layout.activity_login);
    final EditText username = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userloginname);
    final EditText password = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userpassword);
    TextView neighbourView = new TextView(this);
    Button button_test;
    button_test = (Button) this.findViewById(id.btnLogin);
    button_test.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String usersname = username.getText().toString();
            final String passwoord = password.getText().toString();
            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(String.valueOf(username));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(password));
            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {@Override
                public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        ParseUser.logInInBackground(usersname, passwoord, new LogInCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseUser User, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                if (User != null) {
                                    // user name is in the database
                                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user name does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
});
}
```

And my XML

```
<!-- language: xml -->
     <!--  Username Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/username"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/userloginname"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/password"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/userpassword" />
    <!-- Login button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/loginButton"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
user.setUsername(String.valueOf(username));
 user.setPassword(String.valueOf(password));
```

to

```
user.setUsername(String.valueOf(usersname ));
user.setPassword(String.valueOf(passwoord));
```

You are mixing up the real text and the textview's string equivalent.